# Unable to see the closed issues with the Github API

Tags: api, github

I'm using the `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues` endpoint to count the closed issues of several Github repositories and to measure their resolution time, but for some reason there are only issues with `state : "open"`, which is the default state.

The documentation says that `state` *Indicates the state of the issues to return. Can be either open, closed, or all. Default: open*

Doc : https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository

For example this repository is supposed to have 2 open and 7 closed issues but as you can see the endpoint fails to return the closed ones. Is there a possibility to see the closed issues ?

API : https://api.github.com/repos/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/issues

Web : https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/issues

Comment: Add `?state=closed`, like so: `https://api.github.com/repos/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/issues?state=closed`

Comment: It returns a `"message": "Not Found"`

Comment: I sort of see the problem is it changes dashes to entities, dunno why. [Perhaps now?](https://api.github.com/repos/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/issues?state=closed)

Comment: I can't even find what is the difference between the two urls you proposed :-| Have no idea what makes the second works perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution proposed by user orhtej2 in comment works perfectly : `https://api.github.com/repos/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/issues?state=closed`

Comment: You can also set `state=all` to see both closed and open issues